# How to change border radius based on click event in angular 6

Tags: html, css, angular, angular5, angular6

I have 2 different html file,

test1.html
test2.html
test2.component.ts

1) test1.html :

```
   <div style="width:100%;height:20%"></div>
```

2) test2.html :

If I click rectangle function, test1.html border radius should change as 0px.

If I click roundCorder function, test1.html border radius should change as 10px;

```html
<img (click)="rectangle()" [src]="imgSrc" (mouseover)="rectangleHover()" (mouseout)="rectangleOut()" style="height:100px;float:left;margin:15px;" >
       <img (click)="roundCorner()" [src]="imgSrc1" (mouseover)="roundHover()" (mouseout)="roundOut()" style="height:100px;float:left;margin:15px;">
```

3) test2.components.ts :

```
  roundCorner(){
     // want to change test1.html file div border radius as 10px;
  }
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: tip: use [style.border-radius]="what ever"

Comment: based on the condition @Eliseo

Comment: try something and edit the question. I don't know if you have one, two or three components or If your problem is communication between components or simply binding [style.property]. Sorry, I can't do anymore

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass the HTML and add the styles to it  as below,

HTML

```
<div #divElement style="width:100%;height:20%"></div>
<button (click)="rectangle(divElement)">Rectangle</button>
<button (click)="circle(divElement)">Circle</button>
```

Typescript

```
rectangle(divElement) {
    divElement.style.borderRadius = '0px'
    console.log(divElement.style)
  }
  circle(divElement) {
    divElement.style.borderRadius = '50%'
    console.log(divElement.style)
  }
```

[**Stakblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lxejfo)

Comment: 2 different html and typescript files @Aravind. How can I do this?

Comment: can you please elaborate

Comment: As per my understanding there is only one html file both are`test1.html`

Comment: test1.html and test2.html. See the first line of my question. Please read properly

Comment: 2 different html files nu mention pannirukan parunga. and also see my codes

Comment: Oh sorry pakkala. neenga konjam stackblitz edit panni parunga please

Comment: see the below example of @Vaibhav Kumar Goyal's. Its looking fine. But I'm getting more error. I can't fix that. Can you please help me

Answer (score 0):

Is test1 is your parent component and test2 is your child component. If thats the case, you can emit an event using EventEmitter() with value rectangle/square from Child component. You can read that event in parent component and update the DOM using ngStyle.

Answer (score 0):

**test1.html**

```
<div #elem1 style="width:100%;height:20%"></div>
```

**test2.html**

```
 <img #elem2 (click)="rectangle()" [src]="imgSrc" (mouseover)="rectangleHover()" (mouseout)="rectangleOut()" style="height:100px;float:left;margin:15px;" >
           <img (click)="roundCorner()" [src]="imgSrc1" (mouseover)="roundHover()" (mouseout)="roundOut()" style="height:100px;float:left;margin:15px;">
```

**test2.component.ts**

```
import {ElementRef,Renderer2} from '@angular/core';
@ViewChild('elem2') el:ElementRef;

constructor(private rd: Renderer2,sharedService:SharedService) {
   this.el=this.sharedService.get();
}



 roundCorner(){
     // want to change test1.html file div border radius as 10px;
    this.el.style.border-radius='10px';

  }
rectangle(){
this.el.style.border-radius='0px';
}
```

**shared.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
class SharedService{
let elem1:any
set(element:any)
{
  this.elem1=element;
}
get(){
return this.elem1;
}
```

**test1.component.ts**

```
@ViewChild('elem1'):ElementRef
constructor(sharedService:SharedService,elementRef:ElementRef){
}
ngOnInit()
{
    this.sharedService(this.elem1);
}
```

What you have to use is a shared service to access this dom element reference variable between both the components and then set the property of border-radius respectively

import {SharedService} in both the component.ts files and app.module.ts and put SharedService under providers array in app.module.ts

Comment: I'm getting error in shared.service.ts file. Cannot find name 'let' , 'set','get' and Cannot find name 'element'. Did you mean 'Element'?

Comment: test1.component.ts alse same error cannot find name 'sharedService' . Inside ngOnInit()

Comment: i have added a few changes @sathishkumar